# Calling a DLL on a remote machine

Tags: c++

How can I go about calling a dll from a remote machine in c++? I'm trying to call a dll without actually storing it on the local machine. I have searched on the internet but am not able to find an answer. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Google for the following: Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), Distributed Component Object Mode (DCOM),  and Windows RPC.

Comment: Use map drives with symbolic links for distributed system and on cloud storage. Once mapped, all the files (including your dll) will act like a local drive in your system.

Comment: It's a bit hard to fill in your question, as you leave out quite a few things. And as a side effect, we can't really estimate your technical skills either. For instance, do you know that a DLL is loaded into a process? And that a process contains exactly one executable? Which executable do you expect to run on the remote machine?

Comment: MSalters, thanks for helping me to clarify what I'm looking to do. My skills are pretty novice at best. I'm trying to learn as I go, but if you have any suggestions as to other paths I should take I would be grateful for the info. I do understand that a DLL is loaded into a process and that a process contains only one executable. I'm looking to inject a remote DLL into a process on the local machine without copying the DLL to the local machine. I think that would answer your last question - I'm not trying to run an executable on the remote machine because the process and injector are local.

Comment: So I have been reading up on mapping a drive using WNetAddConnection2(), but I am trying to accomplish this via FTP. Is it a better idea to search for a different function to accomplish it via FTP or change protocl and use the function I referenced?